# Bootstrap column split issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I want to make OUTBOUND and INBOUND flight information in separate columns splitted 6 by 6.

Idea of current HTML/LESS is that Outbound and Inbound divs must respect each other on the height property. For example if Outbound flight has two connections and Inbound is a direct flight both will stay the same size.

This is how to looks like at the moment:

[image]

I want to put Outbound and Inbound in the separate bootstrap columns (6x6) in order to keep distance between inbound and outbound elements. But unfortunately it doesn't work. Could you please help me to figure out how could I achieve that? Of course I can just adjust a margin but does it robust solution if I want to use it on different screen sizes?

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQvJpK)

HTML:

```
<span class="roundtrip">
  <div class="trip col-md-6">Outbound
    <div class="flight">Los Angeles</div>
    <div class="flight-path"></div>
    <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
    <div class="connection">5hr wait</div>
    <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
    <div class="flight-path"></div>
    <div class="flight">New York</div>
    <div class="connection">2hr wait</div>
    <div class="flight">New York</div>
    <div class="flight-path"></div>
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
  </div>
  <div class="trip col-md-6">Inbound
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
    <div class="flight-path"></div>
    <div class="flight">Los Angeles</div>
  </div>
</span>
```

LESS:

```
.roundtrip {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.trip {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px 3px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flight {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.flight-path {
  width: 6px;
  min-height: 85px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #6090FF;
}

.connection {
  height: 40px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Well, the main problem is that you're  trying to use directly contradictive styles on the same elements: notice `.trip {width: 100px; margin: 0px 3px;}` vs. `.col-md-6 {width: 50%; float: left;}` and so on. Beside this I'm also afraid that in general Bootstrap-like grid is not quite compatible with CSS flex stuff, so you'll face a lot of minor and not so minor) issues trying to combine both for the same elements. [Here's](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/qOdyKG?editors=110) quick&dirty fix I sketched (but the rest is very dependent on exact look you're planning).

Comment: Personally I'd suggest your "I can just adjust a margin", because "robust solution if I want to use it on different screen sizes" is nothing but a few `@media {}` patterns (actually look at Bootstrap grid columns CSS code to learn a few).